# Pandas append data to each new row without column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe values as shown below:

```
Feature     camera    start      shy       much      out
Value     -0.669522 -0.395353 -0.203041 -0.180339 -0.170925
Feature     camera    start      out       much      game
Value     -0.676154 -0.410896 -0.171128 -0.170666 -0.161646
Feature     camera    start      much      out       game
Value     -0.636111 -0.399443 -0.185039 -0.158133 -0.155625
Feature     camera    start      shy       out       much
Value     -0.638569 -0.38576  -0.200171 -0.173301 -0.15943
```

I want this to convert into the following format as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Are you running into an error? Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Sir, I want to know how can I do this. Any possible way?

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself?

Comment: yes, I am trying:): but all in vain.

Comment: Okay, so update you post and include the code you have tried along with the outputs. It's great to ask for help, but posting an input and desired output without showing what you have tried.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df['Feature'][i] == 'Feature':
        k.append(i)
df = df.drop(k)
```